# How to transfer Pan Gesture Recognizer from one view to other?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

i have a button which can record voice message. After longpress I create a new view where i can move another button. But pan gesture recognizer doesn't work without tapping again. So could you tell me how to transfer gesture recognizer from one button to another?
So there is 2 methods that i want to use.

```
 @objc func recordTapped(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    textInput.isHidden = true
    
    self.view.addSubview(audioPlayerView)
    audioPlayerView.setAudioPlayer()
    
    timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: NSDate(), repeats: true)
    startRecording()
   

    self.area.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 0.7026969178)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
        self.area.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.1071770917, blue: 0.3669734589, alpha: 0.6900149829)
        

    }, completion: { (success) in
        
    })
  
    
    
    buttonToPlayAudio.isHidden = false
    addImageButton.isHidden = true
}
```

and the second gesture is for new view

```
 @objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //this method i want to call from previous button
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. If I want to call the handler method from the other handler method I would just remove the parameter and call it. Not sure why you would need the gesture recognizer in the handler method.
Maybe describe more clearly what your buttons should do and what they are not doing right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add gesture recognizer to common parent view. When it's called, check if finger is inside the target button. Then add views, and when user releases the finger, check where it happens.